# How to get values from json array in a javascript

Tags: javascript, json, http, get

I'm trying to get values from json array inside a javascript. Below is the part of my javascript file. I'm using `jsondata.value`   to get the values. It's displaying the json data correctly on the console, but `jsondata.value` is not working for getting the values.

Comment: Why did you edit your question and removed the code?  I believe that would have helped someone else.  This question and answer is now confusing no?  Anyway, I'm happy it's working for you

Comment: It was corporate json data. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that your "jsondata" is text in the DOM?  If so, you want to grab the "string" in the DOM and Parse it into a valid JavaScript Object.  To do so, you need to grab it appropriately:

```
var jsondata = document.getElementById("jsonArray").value;
```

Then you need to parse it

```
var jsondataObj = JSON.parse(jsondata);
```

At this point, `jsondataObj` is your data.  If you want to populate this into your grid, simply inject it the way you wanted to.  There is no need for XHRHttpRequest since you already injected your data into the DOM:

```
var gridOptions = {  ... [your options here] };

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');

    new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);

    var jsondata = document.getElementById("jsonArray").value;

    var jsondataObj = JSON.parse(jsondata);

    function isNumeric(n) { 
        return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
    }

    var parsedData = jsondataObj.map(function(obj) {
        return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(memo, key) {
            var value = obj[key];
            memo[key] = isNumeric(value) ? Number(value) : value;

            return memo;
        }, {})
    })

    console.log(parsedData);

    gridOptions.api.setRowData(parsedData);

});
```

Comment: OK, I tried doing what you said, but I'm getting this error:  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input(anonymous function) @ line var jsondataObj = JSON.parse(jsondata);

Comment: So is your input's ID "jsonArray"? like <input id="jsonArray" ...  ?

Comment: Also since you already have the JSON object, why are you making a HTTP Request?  I'm confused about this whole thing.  Can you run this in like codepen or jsfiddle?

Comment: <input type="hidden" value='<%out.println(jsonArray);%>' id="jsonArray"/>

Comment: Because this is how they have shown us in the ag-grid "Loading Data" tutorial. https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-tutorials/index.php Don't know how else to do it. Also, I'm on a corporate network, so can't use jsfiddle or codepen.

Comment: So just try what I showed you above and see if this gives you what you want.  But still I don't see this working because you're not using the XHRHttpRequest correctly.  where ```httpRequest.open('GET', jsondata.value);``` seems strange when the signature is " ..open( method type, url )"  You're putting a JSON value instead of a URL

Comment: Yes, I was trying to do exactly as you wrote, but I get error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.